# Trouble in setting up hadoop in single node mode.

Tags: xml, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am facing trouble in setting up hadoop in single node mode. I followed the instructions as mentioned in the apache website and I know all the daemons are working correctly. When I run JPS this is what I get.

```
31227 DataNode
31536 Jps
31146 NameNode
27642 RemoteMavenServer
31432 ResourceManager
31513 NodeManager
31327 SecondaryNameNode
```

but when I run

```
hadoop dfs -ls /
```

ls: Failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException; Host Details : local host is: "localhost/127.0.0.1"; destination host is: "localhost":9000;

That's what I get.

That is in my core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

That is in my hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>/tmp/datanode</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

And in my mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
     <property>
         <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
         <value>localhost:9001</value>
     </property>
</configuration>
```

Any idea on what I maybe doing wrong? Also I am using hadoop-2.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the following entry exists in /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain